# Go thru Multidimensional array with titles to get info

Tags: javascript, arrays

The week variable is just a representation of the multidimensional array which is built with json, I use other arrays using the same method (not multidimensional) and they work fine.

Array instead of having 0,1,2,3, ... has 'monday', 'thursday', ... has name for their first level.

```html
var week = {monday: [1,2,3,4],thursday: [1,2,3,4],wednesday: [1,2,3,4], tuesday: [1,2,3,4], friday: [1,2,3,4]};

while (week.length != 0){
  day = week.shift();
  for (i = 0; i< 3; i++){
    console.log(day[i]);
  };
}
```

Gives an error saying length and shift are no functions.

Comment: your week variable is not a valid JS object

Comment: An object can always hold values as `key:pair` only, here you have `manday: [1],[2]..` which doesn't makes sense

Comment: Your question is unclear. Provide also HTML and reformulate the question omitting not showed references.

Comment: please read the text before the code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved with jquery

```html
$.each(week, function(key, val){
    console.log(key);
 for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++){
      console.log(val);
 }
});
```

Comment: you can achieve same with javascript , please refer this link - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/Rdexam

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you want to do something like this:

```
var week = {monday: [1,2,3,4],thursday: [1,2,3,4],wednesday: [1,2,3,4], tuesday: [1,2,3,4], friday: [1,2,3,4]};

var dayInput = "thursday";// $('.days input');
while (week.length != 0){
  var day = week[dayInput].shift();
  for (i = 0; i< 3; i++){
    $('.days input').val($('.days input').val()+day[i]);
    console.log(dayInput.shift());
  };
}
```

But your json object is wrong (syntactically and structurally).

Comment: Like I said It was just a representation! not the actual variable!